# Lightweight Email Client for OS X

Tags: osx, email-client

Are there any good *lightweight* email clients for OS X

### Features I'm looking for:

- Under 50MB of disk space used by core application
- Support multiple accounts/inboxes
- Runs in background
- Uses very little RAM memory
- Push notifications using Notification Center within OSX

Comment: How strict is the 50MB disk space requirement? And what do you consider "very little RAM"?

Comment: Have you looked at the built-in Mail client?

Answer (score 4):

I just like [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/thunderbird/).

I have not used it on mac so there may be *slight* differences from Windows.

- My full install (excluding user data) is ~52MB so while that pushes your envelope slightly that should still match fine.
- Thunderbird fully supports many accounts (I generally run with about a dozen accounts).
- Ram usage is pretty good (at least on Windows).
- If by runs in background you mean can be hidden then yes - although there may be a [bug with that](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2766239) - on Windows I generally run it minimizing to a tray icon.
- **I don't know** it's notification method in OSX.

Comment: Thunderbird is approximately 113.4 MB installed on the Mac. On my Mac, Thunderbird uses 149.7 MB of RAM (85.6 MB private). For comparison OS X's Mail.app uses around 64 MB of RAM (34 MB private).

Thunderbird does use the OS X Notification Center.